# segmentation fault when trying to deference pointer : C

Tags: c, pointers

I was trying to implement circular queue functionality. I am a C++ coder and I found it surprising that in C, struct cannot have member functions. Anyway this is my implementation:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



struct node
{
    int nvalue;
    struct node *next;
};

struct CLlist
{
    struct node* head;
    struct node* tail;
    int size;
};

void insert(struct CLlist *l,int num)
{
    struct node *n=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    n->nvalue=num;
    n->next=NULL;

    if((l->head==l->tail)==NULL)
    {
        l->head=l->tail=n;
    }
    else if(l->head==l->tail && l->head!=NULL)
    {
        l->head->next=n;
        l->tail=n;
        l->tail->next=l->head;
    }
    else
    {
        l->tail->next=n;
        l->tail=n;
        l->tail->next=l->head;
    }
    l->size++;
}

void print(struct CLlist *l)
{
    int idno=1;
    printf("printing the linked list with size as %d\n",l->size);
    struct node *cptr;
    for(cptr=(l->head);cptr!=(l->tail);cptr=cptr->next)
    {
        printf("The idno is %d and the number is %d\n",idno,cptr->nvalue);
        idno++;
    }
    //this is to print the last node in circular list : the tail node
    idno++;
    cptr=cptr->next;
    printf("The idno is %d and the number is %d\n",idno,cptr->nvalue);
}


int main()
{
    struct CLlist a;
    struct CLlist *l;
    l=&a;

    insert(l,2);
    insert(l,5);
    insert(l,7);
    insert(l,10);
    insert(l,12);
    print(l);


    return 0;
}
```

I get segmentation fault in the line

*printf("The idno is %d and the number is %d\n",idno,cptr->nvalue);*

why does the error occur? I guess I am not passing l <strike>by pointer</strike> by value (passing pointers as by value) properly. could somebody help me in pointing out where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: @user3386109,, how could it be null?,, does that mean l is null?? but I am doing insert operations. could you explain as an answer post here. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has two issues, the first one more serious.

Your first issue is that the `head` and `tail` members of your CLlist structure are not being initialized to `NULL`, which can (non-deterministically) keep any real data from being stored in your structure. This can be fixed by adding the following 2 lines in `main` just before the first `insert` call:

```
l->head = NULL;
l->tail = NULL;
```

Your second problem is in this line:

```
if((l->head==l->tail)==NULL)
```

While it looks like this is comparing both `l->head` and `l->tail` to `NULL`, it's actually comparing `l->head` to `l->tail`, and then comparing that boolean result to `NULL`, which is effectively `0`. The line should be changed to:

```
if((l->head == NULL) && (l->tail == NULL))
```

This will individually test both the `head` and `tail` pointers, and will only take that branch if they are both NULL.

Comment: Well explained! Doing `struct CLlist l = calloc(1, sizeof(struct CLlist));` can also be used instead of statically creating the head node, but in this situation it can be left as a matter of preference.

Answer (score 5):

You never initialize the variable `a` in the `main` function, so its contents is *indeterminate* and using the members of that structure will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Does it have something to do the fact that `a.next` gets rubbish there?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg,, Jole C 's answer solved my problem, but I am leaving this question open, as to why 'NOT initializing a' would lead to seg fault?

Comment: The problem with not initializing the CLlist struct is that you have no idea what values are currently in the `head` and `tail` places. Because there is no compiler contract that they will be any specific value (such as NULL), they may be any one of NULL, valid pointer in your program's address space, or somewhere else entirely. This last possibility is what will likely cause your segfaults. While I was proving my answer on my own machine, I actually had it segfault in `insert` and `print` on different runs. The base answer is that using (specifically trusting) uninitialized data is bad.

Answer (score 1):

You have a pointer

```
struct node *cptr;
// You're probably trying to access an unassigned pointer head in the next step
for(cptr=(l->head);cptr!=(l->tail);cptr=cptr->next)
```

As per the standards, there is no requirement that

`a->head` & `a->tail` are initialized to `NULL`

when you did

```
struct CLlist a;
```

Standard ISO/IEC 9899:201x clause 6.7.9->10 states

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, its value is indeterminate.

In fact you're:

```
struct CLlist a;
// missing something here.
struct CLlist *l;
l=&a;
```

Comment: In insert, i check if head and tail are null, if null, i initialize them (or copy the address). Am I wrong there?

Comment: Yes you are: `if((l->head==l->tail)==NULL)` doesn't do what you think it does.  Your compiler should yell at you for this.

Comment: @DineshSashikanth It should be `if (l->head == NULL && l->tail == NULL)`, if you meant to test both pointers to be `NULL`.

Comment: I checked it,, it is not the source of seg fault, but yes amazingly the compiler did not complain.

Comment: yes this answer is partially correct, but the major error was that, head and tail should have been initialized to NULL.

Comment: @xbug : could you explain to me how `head`  and `tail` are initialized using `if (l->head == NULL && l->tail == NULL)` please?

Comment: @sjsam did I say anything about initialization ? That test was obviously fishy: the code read `if((l->head==l->tail)==NULL)`, whereas the intent was clearly to test whether *both* `l->head` and `l->tail` were null.

Comment: @xbug: I overlooked your comment. Sorry about that.